# NetSuite - SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I know that **SuiteScript** is the **NetSuite** platform built on **JavaScript** that enables complete customization and automation of business processes.

I want to know that **SuiteScript** is in demand? How would be the future if I do following certifications

- **SuiteFoundation** Certification
- **SuiteCloud Developer** Certification

Answer (score 5):

I've worked with NetSuite development (SuiteScript 1.0 & 2.0, administration, and integrating NetSuite to many other systems) for about seven years now.  I have no NetSuite certifications, and I have never found a need for them.

That being said, some employers think highly of certifications.  Whether you need the certs really depends on whether you can be self taught and whether the company you want to work for wants you to have them before you are hired.

Comment: @w3bguy hey,  i need to learn the concept of integration but i couldn't find any starting point. can u guide me a little , like where to start because i m new to development and even suitescript.

Comment: @4N335 I would suggest learning the end systems before trying to get into integrating systems.  I see a lot of issues where people try to build integrations before they understand how the target/source systems work.  It usually required rebuilds of the integrations. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on NetSuite for 4 years now. I have done SuiteScript 1.0, 2.0, workflows, searches, reports, etc (all normal admin and developer tasks with NetSuite basically). I am now certified Developer (meaning I passed the 2 exams you mentioned) and because I am a consultant I am now a certified ERP consultant as well. I will probably take the analytics, admin, and eventually SuiteCommerce as well.

So with that background, the answer to your question depends on what you want to do. If you are already working with a company who is using NetSuite, an end client probably doesn't care a ton about the certifications. If you are looking to get a job in this, then it may help you a lot. If you are looking to be a consultant, it will probably be a requirement at some point. For consulting companies, certifications help them look better to clients.

I also will add that I find that by studying for and taking the tests I have learned about features I did not have exposure to prior. This pushes me to learn those areas, talk to others, and better my overall skills beyond the exam itself. If you are only self taught, in my experience, you eventually fall into the "if your own tool is a hammer, than every problem looks like a nail". You won't have all the possible tools to do the best job

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thoughts. Currently I am not working on NetSuite but my employer wants me to do these certifications so then can get business regarding NetSuite customization etc.

Answer (score 1):

I personally found my certifications valuable. Last year, I completed the SuiteFoundation and Administrator exam, both of these guided me into different segments of NetSuite I had never used before.

I'm currently studying for the SuiteCloud developer exam, and I've had the same experience. It's forcing me to look into new modules and test out new functionality. With that being said, I'm a jr. level developer at best, so combining my js training with NetSuite-specific training is relevant.

There is a solid website that recently did a informal survey on this topic, if you want to learn more about value added from NS certifications you can visit: https://netsuite.smash-ict.com/

I recommend all NS newbies to complete the SuiteFoundation training. This applies to everyone, developers, admins, and end-users.

Answer (score 0):

My certifications have helped me in my long-term goal to become a NetSuite Developer. I currently hold the Applications Developer and I'll tell you that it is in need of more developers that also have the knowledge to build business processes. I have had recruiters calling me all the time and I haven't worried about not being able to get a position. My certification has doubled/tripled my salary and opened so many doors.